# Can I manage my app and devices using AirWatch?

Tags: ios, airwatch

We are developing iOS application and going to distribute it in Enterprise account. Want to integrate AirWatch and have several questions about this service:

1. Can we deliver some content to our App (Documents folder inside our
       App) using AirWatch and how? *
2. Can we schedule the update of new version of our app on devices?
3. Can we manage bluetooth and WiFi on
   devices (turn on/off)?

   - for example load new photos to Apps Documents folder - to all, or some devices. If yes, how? - Does exist some UI interface for it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use an MDM to deliver app configurations that are provided to the app through user defaults. You can't use MDM to deliver content. Your app should fetch the required content from a server. You can push new versions of your app via the MDM. You can distribute wifi network profiles (wifi settings/passwords).  You cannot turn wifi or Bluetooth on/off.

Answer (score 0):

1 No. You can deliver key-value data, not content. You could use push notifications to notify the app, and embed into your app an offline content manager to download new data

2 Yes. When a new version is ready you can push that to the devices. A notification will be sent and once they're online they'll and try to download the app. User will also be able to download apps manually, browsing a catalog of your enterprise-distributed apps

3 Yes and no. You can set policies to restart automatically the wifi and bluetooth after 1 hour, not completely turn them on/off

Comment: What is "offline content manager"? and how I can embed it in my app (if you mean that "offline content manager" is part of AirWatch)? Thank you @Luca!

Comment: It's not a part of AirWatch, I meant that we write our own custom code to download  a list of files hosted on our server, check if those files are already available on the mobile device file system and, if not , we provide software to download it. You should also consider the case where a new version of the same file is uploaded to the server, or even removed, etcetera.